# Python: "choice" Function does not seem to be working as I want it to.

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from random import choice
def motiv():
    motiv1 = mLabel = Label(text='Waste not, want not', fg="red").pack()
    motiv2 = mLabel = Label(text='Sticks and stones', fg="red").pack()
    motiv3 = mLabel = Label(text='Keep holding on', fg="red").pack()
    motiv4 = mLabel = Label(text='Hold On, Pain Ends', fg="red").pack()

    ranMotiv = [motiv1, motiv2, motiv3, motiv4]
    print (choice(ranMotiv))

mGui = Tk()

mGui.geometry('450x450+500+150')
mGui.title('RMM')

mLabel = Label(text='Welcome to the Random Motivation Machine', fg="red").pack()

mButton = Button(text = "Click for Some Motivation", command = motiv)
mButton.pack()

mGui.mainloop()
```

There are no errors, but it keeps printing out all of those texts at the same time, when I'm wanting it to only print out only one of them at random.

My goal is to have someone press the button and out pops a random phrase in the GUI window.

So someone presses the button and only one of any of the four text phrases comes out on the window:

1.Waste not, want not.

2.Sticks and stones

3.Keep holding on.

4.Hold on, Pain Ends.

I believe my troubles are arising from this area right here:

```
ranMotiv = [motiv1, motiv2, motiv3, motiv4]
print (choice(ranMotiv))
```

Does anyone have any ideas? This is just a very small pet project of mine. I've only been using Python for less than a few months so I'm not very astute. I'm running Python 3.2.5 by the way. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Don't pack the labels right away. Create a list of the texts and then `random.choice` one of them, turn that one into a label and pack

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish I would have thought of that earlier. It definitely makes a lot of sense. I just implemented your advice and it runs very nicely just how I want it. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

# Place the messages outside of the function so that they are not
# re-created each time the button is pressed
messages = ['Waste not, want not', 'Sticks and stones',
'Keep holding on', 'Hold On, Pain Ends']

def motiv():

    # Just update the text of the Label instead of create a whole new one
    message["text"] = choice(messages)

mGui = Tk()

mGui.geometry('450x450+500+150')
mGui.title('RMM')

mLabel = Label(text='Welcome to the Random Motivation Machine', fg="red").pack()

mButton = Button(text = "Click for Some Motivation", command = motiv)
mButton.pack()

# Make a Label to hold the messages that will be updated with each click of the button
message = Label(fg="red")
message.pack()

mGui.mainloop()
```

Instead of just tacking a new message to the bottom of the GUI, this method is cleaner and just updates the text of the message.  It also fixes the problem of messages running off of the GUI (you can see this by clicking the button like 30 times).

Comment: I ran the code and it works as I want it to, but I'm a little confused as to what the message["text"] = choice(messages) mean in the motiv function. Specifically what is the message["text"] doing/what is it? Sorry, as I said, I'm inexperienced here. Thank you.

Comment: @ZacHall: Certainly.  `message` is the Label instance.  `message["text"]` is the text option of `message`.  You could also do `message["fg"] = "green"` to change the foreground color to green.  Basically, any option that a Tkinter Label (or any other Tkinter widget for that matter) has can be configured like that.  To see all available options, you can call a Tkinter widget's `keys` method like so:  `<widget>.keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

I originally posted this as a comment, but it turned out to be the answer, so I'm reposting it here:

The problem is that `Label(text='Waste not, want not', fg="red").pack()` packs the label right away. Doing this with all labels causes them to be packed. It doesn't matter if you call `random.choice` later because the labels have already been packed into your GUI.

If you want to create a random label from a pool of labels, What you want to do is this:

```
def motiv():
    myLabels = ['Waste not, want not', 'Sticks and stones', 'Keep holding on', 'Hold On, Pain Ends']
    chosenLabel = random.choice(myLabels)
    randMotiv = Label(text=chosenLabel, fg="red").pack()
```

Comment: Did you intend to use `chosenLabel` when creating the label widget?